# How to use Regular Expression In Find and Replacement

Tags: regex, csv, dreamweaver

I've one CSV file which has almost 50k records. I want to remove the unnecessary records from this file. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this by Regex through Find and Replacement?

The data looks like this:

```
Item Code,,Qty
CMAC-389109,,6
,Serial No.,
,954zg5,
,ffnaw8,
,gh8731,
,gxj419,
,hc6y9q,
,y65vh8,
CMAC-394140,,1
,Serial No.,
,4cu3z7,
```

and I want to convert this data to below format:

```
ItemCode,Serial Number,Qty
CMAC-389109,"954zg5, ffnaw8, gh8731, gxj419, hc6y9q, y65vh8",6
CMBM-394140,"4cu3z7",1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex which captures two groups (`Item Code` and `Shelf`):

```
^([^,]*?)(?:,(?:[^,]+)?){5},([^,]+),.*$
```

I don't know what syntax DW uses to reference groups. But usually it's either `$n` or `\n`, so in your case, you can put `$1, $2` in the "replacement" field of the search/replace box. Or `\1, \2`.

---

If you have access to a Linux environment (OS-X and Cygwin should work too), you can use the command-line tools `cut` and `grep` to accomplish this quite easily:

```
 cat <filename> | cut -d ',' -f 1,7 | grep -v "^,$" > <output_file>
```

The parameters I used on `cut` are:

**-d**
    Delimiter (by which character the fields are separated)

**-f**
    Fields (which fields to include in the output).

... and `grep`:

**-v**
    Invert pattern: Only include lines in output *not* matching the regex.

Given your data in your question, the above command will yield this result:

```
Item Code,Shelf
CMAC-386607,M5-2
CMAC-389109, F2-3
```

---

This should also be quite efficient, as `cut` works on a stream, and only loads as much data into memory as necessary. So you don't need to load the whole file before executing the task. It being a large file, this might be handy.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I am aware of this. However, this is the first solution that came to my mind. I am currently working on a regex. In the mean-time, this might help the user already. Most work-places have access to a Linux environment anyway, so I thought this might be helpful during the wait.